# Jenkins jobs migration from Cloudbees plugin to open source plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, open-source, cloudbees

How can we migrate jenkins jobs from a proprietary plugin to it's open-source alternate plugin? We are migrating from cloudbees to open-source jenkins and hence needs to give up proprietary plugins, but there are many jobs created using proprietary plugins. Any pointers would be appreciated.